# Add custom tileserver layer to QGIS

Tags: qgis

I created a custom web TileServer app that serves map tiles using a specific url in the form

```
localhost/2/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
```

`z, x, y` are tile coordinates (like for instance in OpenLayers or Google)

How can I add a layer from this tileserver to QGIS?

Comment: If you go to the **Browser Panel** (if it's not enabled, you can go to the menubar `View > Panels > Browser Panel`), right-click the Tile Server (XYZ), select `New connection...`, you can then enter your tile coordinates which should then load as a layer :)

Answer (score 3):

As @joseph points out, the **XYZ tile provider** will do what you’re after.

This was [introduced in QGIS 2.18](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog218/#feature-native-support-of-xyz-tile-layers). I’m not sure if this has been back ported to any older versions like 2.14

I used it with a local tile cacheing proxy I wrote in Python. This was so I could use base maps when my internet connection goes down.

Be aware that that QGIS has tile cacheing built in, and this also applies to the XYZ provider.

Last time I looked at the QGIS code, it seems QGIS caches the 256 most recent tiles. And I don’t know of any way to clear this cache, other than restarting QGIS.

So if you change your tiles and wonder why you’re still getting ‘stale’ tiles in QGIS, that’s why ;-)